# Can you use Runtime Manager with Mule 3.8.1 Runtime CE?

Tags: mule

I'm totally new to Mule, so my question may seem ridiculous, so sorry up front.  :-)

I downloaded the Mule Standalone Runtime 3.8.1 CE software and wanted to see if I can get it set up to work with the web Runtime Manager, but the instructions say to run the "amc_setup" batch file in the "bin" folder. In my "bin" folder where I extracted the Mule Runtime 3.8.1 CE files, I don't find the "amc_setup" batch file. Have I done something wrong?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**

The **[Mule Runtime Manager](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/)** uses the **[Runtime Manager Agent](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/runtime-manager-agent)**, which [cannot be deployed on the CE runtime engines](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/runtime-manager-agent).

> The Runtime Manager Agent is only available for Enterprise versions of Mule runtime, not for Community versions. Currently, the Runtime Manager Agent supports Mule 3.6.0 or later.
> <sup>*-https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/runtime-manager-agent*</sup>

In general, just expect that unfortunately, all of Mule's "good" features are not available on the **CE** runtime engines.